# Pushing data from one column to another in excel based a new data coming to the existing column

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro code for pushing the existing data from one column to another column if there is a new data coming to the first column.

Eg: I have data as "Aman" in B1, I want this to be moved to C1 when a new data is coming to B1. This is an inventory excel, Aman (B1) is the current user of the asset, now if this asset is getting assigned to Ram. In this case Aman become the previous user (C1) and Ram becomes the current user.

So, the requirement is if in B1 a new name is coming (I have a macro in the file to pull the current user from another sheet) the existing data of this column should be pushed to another column.

Comment: `I have a macro in the file to pull the current user from another sheet` Add `<ShtObject>.Range("C1").Value=<ShtObject>.Range("B1").Value` in your macro before updating the cell B1.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.